# ADF Partial page rendering

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a piece of jspx code in which I want to render(make it visible) a selectOneRadio component conditionally on checking the selectBooleanCheckbox. The first time when check the checkbox the selectOneRadio gets rendered. But when I uncheck , the radio buttons doesnt get invisible.

Im having a `valueChangeListener` in the checkbox code to do this rendering. But this listener doesn't get fired when unchecking the checkbox.

```
<af:selectBooleanCheckbox 
    id="sbc2"                                                                        
    text="#{viewcontrollerBundle.CB_TYPE_VIDEO_CHAT}"                                                                           
    selected="#{row.videoChatEnabled}"                                                                          
    disabled="#{row.videoChatEnabled}"                                                                                                                                                           
    valueChangeListener="#{pageFlowScope.servicesbean.ValueChangeListener}"                                                                          
    binding="#{pageFlowScope.servicesbean.videoChatBinding}"
    autoSubmit="true"                                                                   
/>

<af:selectOneRadio 
    id="videoDirection2"
    visible="false"
    value="#{bindings.videoDirection.inputValue}"
    contentStyle="margin-left:0px"                                                                    
    immediate="true">
```

Does anyone know why this behaviour is prevalent?

Comment: Can you improve the formatting of your posted code?

Comment: Whats the code in your ValueChangeListener?

Comment: Add partialTriggers for videoDirection2

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do needs a partial refresh for render/un-render the element.

Here is the sample:

```
          <af:panelGroup partialTriggers="checkid">
            <af:commandButton text="moo" rendered="#{backing_1.check.value}"
                              partialTriggers="checkid"/>
          </af:panelGroup>
          <af:selectBooleanCheckbox text="selectBooleanCheckbox 1"
                                    label="Label 1"
                                    binding="#{backing_1.check}" id="checkid"
                                    autoSubmit="true"/>
```

The above example show/hide the button based on the checkbox. Note that the button is wrapped in a panel to aid in the partial refresh.

Referenced from: https://community.oracle.com/thread/629222?start=0&tstart=0